# How to get the user's Yahoo GUID using openid?

Tags: openid, lightopenid

Is there a way to get the user's Yahoo GUID? I'm using lightopenid and can perfectly extract user's email, name, and openid id but not its yahoo guid.

Comment: I thought the whole point of OpenID was to provide generic login info, without having to expose provider-specific details like this. The better question is, "Why do you need their Yahoo GUID?"